# Which javac.exe is used by ant javac task?

Tags: java, ant, compilation, javac

I am facing one problem.  I renamed `javac.exe` on my machine and noticed that ant `javac` task still works fine.

Does anybody know from where its getting javac.exe?

Comment: Did you take a look at its [documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html)?

Comment: It probably comes with its own copy. Out of curiosity, why did you rename javac?

Comment: Check your system path & Java path. It might pick up the javac.exe from there. Something similar had happened to me. I had jdk6 & jdk7 installed, but jdk7's bin folder was in the system path & hence it was picking the java.exe from there.

Comment: I did and I think javac should be somehere in my machine for ant to use it. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @Hunter one of my friend was facing an issue and out of no where he renamed this file and reported that ant task is still able to find javac

Comment: @RBK I checked everywhere (including Sky and earth :)) but still cant find javac on my machine

Comment: @Manan there are real problems out there

Comment: Stop wondering where it is and set it explicitly using the `executable` attribute of the `javac` task.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, I believe, that by default Ant tries to execute the java compiler class directly with this code:

```
try {
        Class c = Class.forName ("com.sun.tools.javac.Main");
        Object compiler = c.newInstance ();
        Method compile = c.getMethod ("compile",
            new Class [] {(new String [] {}).getClass ()});
        int result = ((Integer) compile.invoke
                      (compiler, new Object[] {cmd.getArguments()}))
            .intValue ();
        return (result == MODERN_COMPILER_SUCCESS);

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (ex instanceof BuildException) {
            throw (BuildException) ex;
        } else {
            throw new BuildException("Error starting modern compiler",
                                     ex, location);
        }
    }
```

The code came from [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.ant/ant/1.8.3/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/compilers/Javac13.java#Javac13).

Which means that if the library tools.jar is on the current classpath of Ant, it will pickup the class and launch it. This results in the fact that javac.exe can be renamed to whatever you want, it will still work. So to answer your question, it actually executes none of any "javac.exe".

There are other implementations of the Javac task, but I think this is the default one for all compilers 1.3+

Comment: This is not isolated. I believe Tomcat does the same thing to compile JSP's for example, if I recall correctly at least.

Answer (score -1):

You could try starting [here](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/javac.html) and check what is configured in global `build.compiler` property, it may be pointing somewhere else