# Ant Java Major/Minor 51.0 issue even though 1.6 is targeted

Tags: java, ant

I have a major.minor version 51.0 exception in my java code. I am using Ant to compile and run.

I understand that this issue is because my java code is being compiled as 1.7 and then being run as 1.6. However in my Ant script I am explicitly targeting 1.6 and cant find the issue.

My ant script is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252" ?>
<!--Ant buildfile generated by Oracle JDeveloper-->
<!--Generated 07-Mar-2014 09:29:47-->
<project name="SVN Test" default="all" basedir=".">



    <path id="classpath">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/lib">
            <include name="**/*.jar"/>
        </fileset>
    </path>

    <property name="classes" value="${basedir}/target/classes"/>
    <property name="javac.debug" value="on"/>
    <property name="javac.nowarn" value="off"/>
    <property name="javac.deprecation" value="off"/>
    <property name="jar.dir" value="${basedir}/target/jar"/>
    <property name="jar.name" value="jiraClient.jar"/>

    <target name="clean">
        <tstamp/>
        <delete includeemptydirs="true" quiet="true">
            <fileset dir="${classes}" includes="**/*"/>
        </delete>
    </target>

    <target name="init">
        <tstamp/>
        <mkdir dir="${classes}"/>
        <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    </target>

    <target name="compile" depends="init">
        <javac  destdir="${classes}" classpathref="classpath"
                debug="${javac.debug}" nowarn="${javac.nowarn}"
                deprecation="${javac.deprecation}" encoding="Cp1252" source="1.6"
                target="1.6">
            <src path="${basedir}/src/main/java"/>
        </javac>
    </target>

    <target name="run" depends="init, compile">
        <java classname="uk.co.griffithswaite.jiraclient.jiraClient">
            <classpath>
                <pathelement location="${classes}"/>
                <path refid="classpath"/>
            </classpath>
        </java>
    </target>
</project>
```

My JAVA_HOME is C:\Oracle\Middleware\jdk160_24
My java -version is "1.6.0_24"
My Ant version is "1.7.1"

I don't understand how I am getting a 51.0 exception when my Ant is 1.6?

Comment: Double check that you dont have any other jar file bundled was compiled using Java 7

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10543336/which-javac-exe-is-used-by-ant-javac-task

Comment: Octopus thats exactly it, the external jar is complied in 1.7. Now the question is: is javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar available in 1.6?